# failed to install ubuntu 12.04 with usb stick

Tags: installation, usb

I am using ubuntu 10. I downloaded the iso file of ubuntu 12.04 desktop version, then burnt it into my USB stick(8GB), and everything seemed ok.

Now I restarted the notebook, and managed to get to the Ubuntu Desktop, but only after waiting for a good amount of time. After doing so, I proceed to clicking on the button "install Ubuntu", but it seems like it fails to respond properly, and doesn't initiate the Ubuntu installation procedure.

I have tried to do so several times, but the button's functionality just doesn't seem to work.

What could I possibly do to be able to complete the installation?

Comment: could you try running it from the command-line? the installer's name is `ubiquity`. Also, do you want to replace your Ubuntu 10.04 with 12.04, upgrade it to 12.04 or install it alongside the old one?

Comment: I will try your suggestion.

Comment: No this program.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, when your computer boots after you have inserted the liveUSB, you ask it to proceed to boot to the Operating System.

My suggestion is, that rather than doing so, you should reboot your computer (**but leave the USB flash drive where it was**), and when your computer boots, and you come across a list with several choices, select **"Install Ubuntu"**.

It should get you through the same procedure that the "Install Ubuntu" button in the desktop would, and most likely you will be able to install the OS successfully.

Comment: There is no choice "Install Ubuntu" if I reboot my computer without the USB

Comment: You should boot your computer WITH the usb stick. Sorry for not mentioning it on my answer.

Comment: Actually, if I don't edit the file /syslinux/syslinux.cfg in the USB, I will see the prompt "SYSLINUX 3.63 Debian-2008-07-15 ... Boot:" and the system halt. If I change the file, I can see the Ubuntu 12 desktop, But could not install.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include a screenshot or a photograph or something?

Comment: Actually, if I don't edit the file /syslinux/syslinux.cfg in the USB and boot the computer with the USB, I will see a text mode screen like DOS, which prompt "SYSLINUX 3.63 Debian-2008-07-15 ... Boot:" and the system halt. If I change the file then reboot, I can see the Ubuntu 12 desktop, But could not install.   How to paste a photograph?